# Thread-safe async non-re-entrant task

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

How can I structure an async task such that at most one instance of the task runs at a time? If the task is invoked one or more times while a previous instance is running, the previous instance should complete, and then the task should run one additional time.

Task invocation can come from any thread. The task takes no parameters and has no result; the invocation method signature is like this: `Task DoItAsync()`

Use cases for this kind of on-demand, non-re-entrant task include performing background indexing and server synchronization.

Comment: I would use threads and simply abort (by sending an event[!]) a running thread and start a new one or when possible send an event to my thread to signal him to do everything again.

Comment: In this scenario incremental updates are supported. So rather than aborting, it is desirable to run to completion and then run again to pick up any new changes.

Comment: That should work fine too. You just signal your thread to "restart". First you complete the current run and then your thread begins your next (incremental) run.

Comment: An ActionBlock<T> covers the `one at a time, queue invocations` requirement. A timer can post messages to the block periodically to trigger an exeuction

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos With a polled, timer-based approach, you have to wait for the timer to fire, and resources (including battery on mobile) are wasted every time the timer fires unnecessarily.

Comment: @EdwardBrey isn't that what `recurring` means? If you mean "call it as often as I want", the ActionBlock itself is enough

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The word "recurring" was confusing, since it can sound like it's called on a fixed schedule (rather than on demand). It wasn't adding any value, so I removed it. As you indicated, you can indeed call the task as often as you want, and it should always operate correctly. The optimal solution, however, is event based, such that the task is only invoked when a change occurs that would cause it to update something.

Comment: @EdwardBrey and that's exactly what ActionBlock does. You can even create a pipeline of blocks, similar to a powershell or SSIS pipeline. Eg, first block receives a folder path and transmits a list of CSV files, second block receives the individual files, reads and transmits the lines, third block batches the rows and final block writes them to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wrapper that holds the action to be run and takes care of running it as needed so that the caller gets notified after a complete run-through finishes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs an asynchronous action such that at most one instance of the action runs at a time.
/// If the action is invoked one or more times while a previous instance is running,
/// the previous instance completes, and then the action runs one additional time.
/// </summary>
public class RepeatableActionRunner
{
    enum RunState { NotRunning, RunningOnce, RunningAndWillRunAgain };

    readonly Func<Task> action;
    RunState runState;
    Task currentTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    Task nextTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public RepeatableActionRunner(Func<Task> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the action and returns a task that completes when the action completes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This method is thread safe.</remarks>
    public Task RunAsync()
    {
        lock (lockObject) {
            switch (runState) {
                case RunState.NotRunning:
                    return StartTaskAsync();
                case RunState.RunningAndWillRunAgain:
                    return nextTask;
                default:
                    runState = RunState.RunningAndWillRunAgain;
                    return nextTask = currentTask.ContinueWith(_ => {
                        lock (lockObject)
                            return StartTaskAsync();
                    }).Unwrap();
            }
        }
    }

    Task StartTaskAsync()
    {
        runState = RunState.RunningOnce;
        return currentTask = action().ContinueWith(_ => {
            lock (lockObject)
                runState = runState - 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing to be careful of is if `DoItNowAsync` has a long peice of non awaitable code before the first `await` you could hold the lock for a long time. You may want to consider switch to `SemaphoreSlim` and use `await someSemaphoreObject.WaitAsync()` instead of `lock(someLockObject)`

Comment: Also, you need a `.Unwrap()` after your `ContinueWith` to make `nextTask` hold the correct thing. Currently it returns a `Task<Task>`, calling `.Unwrap()` will convert it in to a proper `Task` for you that can be held in `nextTask`

Comment: Couldn't you use an `ActionBlock< T>` for this? By itself it covers all requirements except 'recurring'. A timer that posts requests to it periodically will cover this too

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good catch regarding `Unwrap()`. I updated my answer to include it.

Comment: I think there's still some raciness here that isn't accounted for. Imagine that `DoItNowAsync` is currently executing within the context of a `Task` that's currently stored in `nextTask`. If I understand the context of the question correctly, it's doing all of the work it can find to do. Imagine it has decided that there is no more work to do. Between that decision point (no more work) and its return (at which point it signals completion), another thread adds more work and then enters `DoItAsync`. It enters the lock, gets the (just about to be completed) Task and its work is left unprocessed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In that scenario the new call to DoItAsync will fall through to `nextTask = currentTask.ContinueWith(DoItNowAsync).Unwrap()`, which will cause another instance of DoItNowAsync to run after the first one returns.

Comment: @EdwardBrey - no it will not because `nextTask` has not *yet* completed so your first `if` applies and it gets the Task that is *just* about to be marked as completed

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point. I updated the answer with a fix for the [old, buggy code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43762739/3). It required enough additional bookkeeping that I made the code into a dedicated class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tweaked version of [Edward's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762739/80274) that uses a semaphore to wait so if we do need to wait for the lock to become free we wait asyncronously.

```
readonly SemaphoreSlim _someSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
Task _currentTask = Task.CompletedTask;
Task _nextTask = Task.CompletedTask;

public async Task DoItAsync()
{
    Task taskToAwait;
    await _someSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        if (!_nextTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            taskToAwait =  _nextTask;
        }
        else if(_currentTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            taskToAwait = _currentTask = DoItNowAsync(null);
        }
        else
        {
            taskToAwait = _nextTask = _currentTask.ContinueWith(DoItNowAsync).Unwrap();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _someSemaphore.Release();
    }

    await taskToAwait;
}

async Task DoItNowAsync(Task _)
{
    // Do the work, including async operations.
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for the same reason that the earlier version of my answer won't work. Besides the race condition that Damien identified, there is the problem that a request to re-run the action that comes while _nextTask won't trigger a full re-run.

Answer (score 0):

The [ActionBlock< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) class already allows you to post requests to a block and have it execute them asynchronously using a specified DOP. The default DOP is 1.

By itself, this would ensure that you get only one execution at a time and subsequent requests will get queued. To request an execution according to a schedule, you can use a timer to post requests to the block.

For example:

```
//Block field with gratuitous timestamp
ActionBlock<DateTime> _rebuildBlock;
_rebuildBlock=new ActionBlock<DateTime>(async dt=>await RebuildIndex(dt));

//From any thread:

_rebuildBlock.Post(DateTime.Now);
```

That is enough to queue and execute a request. With the default DOP of 1, only one execution is allowed at a time.

When you have no more requests to send, eg the application terminates, you tell the block to complete and await it to process any pending requests:

```
_rebuildBlock.Complete();
await _rebuildBlock.Completion;
```

You can create a class to abstract the block, or multiple blocks, eg:

```
class MyProcessor
{
    ActionBlock<DateTime> _rebuildBlock;

    MyProcessor()
    {
        _rebuildBlock=new ActionBlock<DateTime>(async dt=>await RebuildIndex(dt));
    }

    public void Rebuild()
    {
        _rebuildBlock.Post(DateTime.Now);
    }

    private async Task  RebuildIndex(DateTime timestamp)
    {
       //...
    }

    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        _rebuildBlock.Complete();
        return _rebuilcBlock.Completion;
    }
}
```

An ActionBlock can be linked to other blocks in the TPL Dataflow namespace to create a pipeline of processing steps, similar to a Powershell or SSIS pipeline.

For example, a pipeline that performs bulk imports of CSV files could look like this:

```
//Create the blocks
var folderBlock=new TransformManyBlock<string,string>(folder=>Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder));
var csvBlock=new TransformBlock<string,DataRow>(filePath=>ParseCsv(filePath));
var batchBlock=new BatchBlock<DataRow>(1000);
var dbBlock=new ActionBlock<DataRow[]>(rows=>RunSqlBulkCopy(rows));

//Link them
var options=new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion=true};
folderBlock.LinkTo(csvBlock,options);
csvBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock,options);
batchBlock.LinkTo(dbBlock,options);

//Process 100 folders
foreach(var path in aLotOfFolders)
{
    folderBlock.Post(path);
}

//Finished with the folders
folderBlock.Complete();
//Wait for the entire pipeline to complete
await dbBlock.Completion;
```

If you want to queue only one request at a time, you can create a pipeline that contains a [BroadcastBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447(v=vs.110).aspx) and an ActionBlock with a queue length of 1:

```
var execOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{BoundedCapacity=1};

var rebuildBlock=new ActionBlock<DateTime>(async dt=>await RebuildIndex(dt),execOptions);
var broadcast=new BroadcastBlock<DateTime>(msg=>msg);    

var options=new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion=true};
broadcast.LinkTo(rebuildBlock,options);
```

After that, anything posted to the broadcast block while `Rebuild` executes will overwrite any previous requests.

Comment: I don't beleive he wants them all queued. I think he wants a max queue size of 1 and once it reaches that size any new requests just get the result of that single queued request.

Comment: @EdwardBrey Degree Of Paralellism. It is a common term used when working with [Sql Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#8f1c24b0454382764ba918fedf349ebb:0) (see `MAXDOP`) and likely where Panagiotis picked it up from.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you combine a [BroadCastBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447(v=vs.110).aspx) and an actionblock queue length of 1 to only keep one request in the combined queue. With a queue of 1, anyone posting to the ActionBlock will have to wait. A broadcastblock though discards requests if there is no one to receive them and keeps only the latest.